# Post to Microsoft translator API not getting any response

Tags: azure, azure-cognitive-services, microsoft-translator

I am trying to use Microsoft Translator API via Postman, but for some reason I am not getting any response.

This is the request's details:

```
post - https://api.cognitive.microsofttranslator.com/translate?api-version=3.0&from=en&to=he

Headers:
Content-Type:application/json
Ocp-Apim-Subscription-Key: ****
Content-Length: 100

body:
[
    {"Text":"I would"}
]
```

I took my key from the Azure portal => RESOURCE MANAGEMENT => Keys => KEY 1. Is that not the right key to use?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

solved by removing the Content-Length header.

Comment: Dear can you please help me. I am working on Microsoft translation api but i am getting NULL value, Please help me its very urgent for me. Thanks in advance